# .htaccess to block access to files in another directory without <directory>

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using the rule below in .htaccess to block bots that hammer my site for the listed .php files, i.e. `mydomain.com/join.php`:

```
<FilesMatch "(signup|register|join|timthumb)\.php$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But how can I also protect the same file names in folders in the tree, i.e. `mydomain.com/otherdirectory/join.php`?

Those file names in other directories are hit less often than root, but I'd still like throw an `forbidden` error rather than the site 404 page.

I tried, and since I'm on a shared server, I can't use the `<Directory>` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in the .htaccess file in root directory:

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
# Files to protect in next line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (join|file1|file2)\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule .+  - [F,NS,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I'm not using the multiviews flag for now; want to test that more.